# how to deploy webcam and text tchat webrtc made with node js

Tags: server, webrtc, webcam

I have a project at school about making a moderation for a webrtc tchat
i find a open source projet online

https://github.com/AkashKarnatak/Ajnabee

with localhost everything is ok

but on my dedicated server , i cant join the website , how to do that ? i didnt find any tutorial

i installed node js and express
i launched node js , server listening at 8080

but when i go to my website, nothing happened

Any help ? i miss something ? perhaps folders rights ?

Thanks for help